# cassandra operation timeout when querying

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a very simple time dataset

```
CREATE TABLE incoming (
    id uuid,
    otime timeuuid,
    data map<text, text>,
    type int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have noticed an error when attempting to do a time based query,  I am following the examples from datastax but find if I do a query such as this

```
SELECT data FROM incoming WHERE otime >= minTimeuuid('2015-09-08 01:00:00') AND otime < maxTimeuuid('2015-09-08 02:00:00') AND type=1 LIMIT 500;
```

I receive the error OperationTimedOut: errors={}

If I change the period to this

```
SELECT data FROM posts WHERE otime >= minTimeuuid('2015-09-08 00:00:00') AND otime < maxTimeuuid('2015-09-08 10:00:00') AND type=1 LIMIT 500;
```

I receive the results with out any error.

I have confirmed that there is data there as I can see entries in otime column reporting 2015-09-08 01:10:06+0000

I have tried including the timezone in the query but the only way I seem to be able to retrieve the data is by having increasing the period or by looking at older timeframes.

I have run nodetool repair and upgraded cassandra to the latest version as well as opscenter, thought it was something to do with ops center as I am now unable to configure the repair service but I am working through that one.

There are no errors in output.log or system.log

I have confirmed this both from the python driver and from the cqlsh.

For the python driver I have increased the timeout thinking it was retrieving to much data and set it all the way to 90 and also reconfigured the timeouts on the cassandra node itself all with no success.

Any ideas

Comment: I am removing all old data to see if there was some corruption

Comment: truncating the table is now allowing data to be retrieved, so this is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run these queries you need to change both schema and query.
Cassandra won't let you include condition after between criteria (after > and <).
Change you schema as

```
CREATE TABLE incoming (
    id uuid,
    otime timeuuid,
    data map<text, text>,
    type int,
    PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
)
```

And query as

```
SELECT data FROM incoming WHERE type=1 and otime >= minTimeuuid('2015-09-08 01:00:00') AND otime < maxTimeuuid('2015-09-08 02:00:00') LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it and report back

Comment: I think it is resolved now after truncating and updating schema but I guess my next question is why did the query succeed if I put the range to 10 hours but not to 1 hour.